# Simple Nested For Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to paste "Area1" 50 times, and "Area2" 50 time right below "Area1" in the same column. My codes run the first 50 times, and replace the first 50 rows when running Area=2. How do I make "Area2" start on a new row, under "Area1"? Thank you :))

```
For Area = 1 To 2
    For Row = 1 To 50
        Sheets("A").Cells(Row, 2) = Sheets("A").Cells(2, 31)
        Next Row       
Next Area
```

Comment: I would suggest not using "Row" as a variable name.

Comment: Question:  Are you trying to put the same data from range("AE2") into all 50 spaces?  Or are you trying to put  range("AE2")  into range("B2") , range("AE3")  into range("B3") , range("AE4")  into range("B4") , etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  A few of them would be:

```
For Area = 1 To 2
    For Row = 1 To 50
        Sheets("A").Cells((Area - 1) * 50 + Row, 2) = Sheets("A").Cells(2, 31)
    Next Row       
Next Area
```

or

```
For Area = 1 To 2
    For Row = (Area - 1) * 50 + 1 To (Area - 1) * 50 + 50
        Sheets("A").Cells(Row, 2) = Sheets("A").Cells(2, 31)
    Next Row       
Next Area
```

or changing `Area` to be zero-based

```
For Area = 0 To 1
    For Row = 1 To 50
        Sheets("A").Cells(Area * 50 + Row, 2) = Sheets("A").Cells(2, 31)
    Next Row       
Next Area
```

or avoiding loops

```
Sheets("A").Cells(1, 2).Resize(50, 1) = Sheets("A").Cells(2, 31)
Sheets("A").Cells(51, 2).Resize(50, 1) = Sheets("A").Cells(2, 31)
```

or, because you are copying the same value to the destination cells, simply

```
Sheets("A").Cells(1, 2).Resize(100, 1) = Sheets("A").Cells(2, 31)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is creating another variable and increment it, in second loop, each time +1. Like this:

```
For Area = 1 To 2
    For Row = 1 To 50
        myRow = myRow + 1
        Sheets("A").Cells(myRow, 2) = Sheets("A").Cells(2, 31)
        Next Row       
Next Area
```